# Doctrine Mongo ODM - select distinct values

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-odm

I need to select distinct values from a mongoDB collection. As is described in docs [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html#selecting-distinct-values) for this can be used "distinct". But it returns only the fields that was used in distinct condition (ArrayIterator object), not as loggable cursor object:

```
    object(Doctrine\MongoDB\ArrayIterator)[1072]
  private 'elements' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 39
      1 => int 47
  private 'commandResult' => 
    array (size=3)
      'values' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 39
          1 => int 47
      'stats' => 
        array (size=5)
          'n' => int 60
          'nscanned' => int 71
          'nscannedObjects' => int 71
          'timems' => int 0
          'cursor' => string 'BasicCursor' (length=11)
      'ok' => float 1
```

Comment: What else did you hope it would return? This is just what distinct does in MongoDB: give you an array of distinct values.

Comment: I expect that distinct in Mongo work as distinct in Doctrine 2 ORM (MySQL DISTINCT with multiple columns - it return an array of values and can also be selected multiple fields from the table). In Mongo ODM module, I got only the field  that i choosed to be as distinct (only one field is selected).

Comment: To be more clear I expect a result as it is described here (for Mysql) - http://www.w3resource.com/sql/select-statement/queries-with-distinct-multiple-columns.php

Comment: Just slap an additional ->count() on the execute() and you are all set!